# How to parse a JSON so that I can loop through elements

Tags: android, json, jsonparser

Below is the given String i am getting from WebService response.

```
{
    "tag": "fetchdwnDetailStatus",
    "status": true,
    "downloadDetails": "[\"[9164666666, 20171001, MADAN LAL CHOURISYA, 16, 1342.6]\",\"[9868476619, 20171001, RAHUL JAIN\\\/CHUNNILAL JAIN, 50, 121]\",\"[9173666666, 20171001, SHRI BALKRISHAN \\\/ DHARMLAL KUR, 13, 3246]\",\"[9833216286, 20171001, SMT CHANDA JAIN\\\/SHRI CHANDMAL , 50, 4502.23]\",\"[7073016885, 20171001, MAHESH KUMAR \\\/ BRAJLAL KUSHWAH, 48, 1560.8]\"]"
}
```

I want to loop through each element of `downloadDetails`, and want to display on screen.

So, far I did

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
if(jObj!=null)
{                         
    arrayFromStringDD = jObj.getJSONArray("downloadDetails");
    try {        
            JSONArray jsonArray = arrayFromStringDD;
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int j=0; j<jsonArray.length(); j++) {
               System.out.println("adding in list==>"+ jsonArray.getString(j));
                list.add( jsonArray.getString(j) );
            } 
     }catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
     }                          
}
```

I am getting not a primitive Type error at line `arrayFromStringDD = jObj.getJSONArray("downloadDetails");`  Please help

**Edit:** As suggested in the post, this is string and not an array. SO I tried this.

```
JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
JsonArray arrayFromStringDD = jsonParser.parse((String) jObj.getString("downloaddata")).getAsJsonArray();
 try {        
            JSONArray jsonArray = arrayFromStringDD; //here I am getting error while converting...
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int j=0; j<jsonArray.length(); j++) {
               System.out.println("adding in list==>"+ jsonArray.getString(j));
                    list.add( jsonArray.getString(j) );
                } 
             }catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: see this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48624125/4448617

Comment: @you can change your json response from server side.

Comment: @Ratilal, unfortunately I cannt change, this is what I am getting from WS.

Comment: you can check my answer.

Comment: please check my answer with output. if you have any query feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
if(jObj!=null)
{                         

try 
{

     String downloadDetails = jObj.getString("downloadDetails");

     String jsonFormattedString = downloadDetails.replaceAll("\\\\", "");

     JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonFormattedString);

     for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

         System.out.println("adding in list==>"+ jsonArray.getString(i));
     }

}
catch (JSONException e) 
{
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

**EDIT**

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
if(jObj!=null)
{                         

try 
{

     String downloadDetails = jObj.getString("downloadDetails");

     String jsonFormattedString = downloadDetails.replaceAll("\\\\", "");

     JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonFormattedString);

     for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

         System.out.println("adding in list==>"+ jsonArray.getString(i));

         String innerArray = jsonArray.getString(i);


         innerArray = innerArray.replace("[","");
         innerArray = innerArray.replace("]","");

         String[] innerValue = innerArray.split(",");

         for (int j = 0; j < innerValue.length; j++){

           Log.i("OUTPUT",":"+innerValue[j]);

         }
     }

}
catch (JSONException e) 
{
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Inner OUTPUT**

```
I/adding in list==>: [9164666666, 20171001, MADAN LAL CHOURISYA, 16, 1342.6]
I/OUTPUT: :9164666666
I/OUTPUT: : 20171001
I/OUTPUT: : MADAN LAL CHOURISYA
I/OUTPUT: : 16
I/OUTPUT: : 1342.6
```

Comment: Thanks Dear.. Could you please also let me know how should I get each element further. I am doing something like.  listResponse.add(jsonArray.getString(i));    List<String> innerList = new ArrayList<String>();
                      for (int i=0;i<listResponse.size();i++){ 
                       
                      innerList =  Arrays.asList(listResponse.get(i));
                       
                      for(int j=0;j<innerList.size();j++)
                      {
                       System.out.println("innerElements==>"+innerList.get(j));
                      }}

Comment: @ManishSuriya please check my Edit answer.

Comment: @ManishSuriya if you solve your problem please select my answer as correct.

Comment: I am getting error at   JSONArray jsonArray1 = jsonArray.getJSONArray(i);02-06 21:04:57.862: W/System.err(2225): org.json.JSONException: Value [9164666666, 20171001, MADAN LAL CHOURISYA, 16, 1342.6] at 0 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
02-06 21:04:57.862: W/System.err(2225):  at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100)
02-06 21:04:57.863: W/System.err(2225):  at org.json.JSONArray.getJSONArray(JSONArray.java:500)

Comment: @ManishSuriya PLEASE CHECK MY EDIT ANSWER AND output.

Answer (score 0):

Retrofit Library will make your life much easier. It supports JSON to java object conversion. 
http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Answer (score 0):

Your `downloadDetails` is of type string and not an array since it is enclosed in "".
So when you try to convert String to ArrayObject you get the error

Look at the below Example and compare it with your json:

```
{
"name":"John",
"age":30,
"cars":[ "Ford", "BMW", "Fiat" ]
}
```

Comment: ok Thanks, I got it its not an array but a String. Could you please help me how can I parse and iterate through the each element. I am doing like this   JsonArray arrayFromStringDD = jsonParser.parse((String) jObj.getString("downloaddata")).getAsJsonArray(); But I am not sure how should I iterate to get the elemnts like in this example Ford, BMW

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add my comments in answer of @Niket Shah

```
try {

            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(text);
            String arrayString = jObj.getString("downloadDetails");

            JSONArray jObjTemp = new JSONArray(arrayString);

            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int j = 0; j < jObjTemp.length(); j++) {
                System.out.println("adding in list==>" + jObjTemp.getString(j));

                list.add(jObjTemp.getString(j));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**And when i get log it shows :**

> I/System.out: adding in list==>[9164666666, 20171001, MADAN LAL CHOURISYA, 16, 1342.6]
>   I/System.out: adding in list==>[9868476619, 20171001, RAHUL JAIN/CHUNNILAL JAIN, 50, 121]
>   I/System.out: adding in list==>[9173666666, 20171001, SHRI BALKRISHAN / DHARMLAL KUR, 13, 3246]
>
> I/System.out: adding in list==>[9833216286, 20171001, SMT CHANDA JAIN/SHRI CHANDMAL , 50, 4502.23]
>
> I/System.out: adding in list==>[7073016885, 20171001, MAHESH KUMAR / BRAJLAL KUSHWAH, 48, 1560.8]

Feel free to comment if you have doubt.

*Happy Coding...*

Comment: Thanks Dear. Really Helped!